# a new pingback on the post comment generated automatically after article published in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, web-deployment, blogs

a new pingback on the post "post title" comment generated automatically after the article published in the WordPress blog.

Please help me with how to avoid a new pingback comment generation and please let me know why its generated automatically? Is there any not following article writing standards?

Comment: I think you need to provide a bit more detail and context so that people are better able to understand your question.

Comment: using WordPress for my blog https://narayanatutorial.com,  in this blog whenever article published then automatically empty comment generated and receiving comment into the administration email inbox.